# Regex to insert words into background declaration of a CSS file

Tags: php, css, regex, replace, text-parsing

I want to parse a CSS file and every time there is `background:[some properties] (12px) (10px) [some properties];` changes to `background:[some properties] right (12px) top (10px) [some properties];

I have tried this regex:

`(background\s*:.*?)\s(\d+([a-z]+|%|))\s+(\d+([a-z]+|%|));`

but it catches:
`background:url(../images/header.jpg) top no-repeat; height:123px; float:left; padding:65px left 0px top 0px  120px;`

You can see in [this fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/x1Qvcg/1), the only string it should catch is this:
`background:url(../images/header.jpg) 10px  0 no-repeat;`
but it catches an extra string.

How do I stop the regex pattern after `;`, so it will not continue to the next css rule? and what is the right pattern here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$result = preg_replace('/\bbackground\s*:[^;]*?\K(\d+(?:px|e[mx]|%)?+\s+)(\d+(?:px|e[mx]|%)?+)/i', 'right $1 top $2', $string);
```

example:

```
<?php

$string = <<<'LOD'
#banner{width:814px; background:url(../images/header.jpg) top no-repeat; height:123px; float:left; padding:65px 0px 0px  120px; font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif; font-size:30px; color:#fff;}

#banner2{width:814px; background:url(../images/header.jpg) 10px  0 no-repeat; height:123px; float:left; padding:65px 0px 0px  120px; font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif; font-size:30px; color:#fff;}

#banner3{width:814px; background:url(../images/header.jpg) left 10px  top 0 no-repeat; height:123px; float:left; padding:65px 0px 0px  120px; font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif; font-size:30px; color:#fff;}
LOD;

$result = preg_replace('/\bbackground\s*:[^;]*?\K(\d+(?:px|e[mx]|%)?+)\s+(\d+(?:px|e[mx]|%)?+)/i', 'right $1 top $2', $string);

print_r($result);
```

pattern details:

`(?:....)` is a non capturing group

`\K` resets all the match from match result before it

`\b` is a word boundary. It's a zero-width assertion, a border between a member of the `\w` character class and another character

`[^;]` is a negative character class that means "all character except `;`"

a quantifier is by default greedy (it catch all that is possible), if you want it catch the less possible (lazy), you must add a question mark after (`*?`, `+?`, `??`, `{1,5}?`)

Comment: Thanks for the effort and the `(\d+(?:px|e[mx]|%)?+\s+)` is great idea but it's not matching anything...

Comment: @user2979757: what's strange! I have tested it and it works! (with your example string)

Comment: thanks @Casimir!!  

it works almost perfectly..  
(I just need to capture 0 with no px after it)  
If you don't mind I wish to understand this black magic ;)  
1. what is the meaning of `:` in `(?:px|e[mx]|%)`  
2. what is the meaning of the `\K` and `\b`  
3. `[^;]*?` can you please explain this voodoo in English? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your regex expects that `background` property will end with two numbers and `;` and does not expect to meet `no-repeat` there. Try this regex

`(background\s*:.*?)\s(\d+([a-z]+|%|))\s+(\d+([a-z]+|%|)).*?;`

Comment: Thanks but this regular expression is not stoping in the semicolon:
and catches all of this:

`background:#fef4e9 url(../images/left-mid.jpg) bottom no-repeat; padding:0px left 0px top 1 2px 0px;`

Comment: Ok. Let's replace non-greed anything `.*?` with everything except `;` `[^;]*`. So we won't match anything behind the `;` and regex should be

`(background\s*:[^;]*)\s(\d+([a-z]+|%|))\s+(\d+([a-z]+|%|))[^;];`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
(background\s*:[^;]*?)\s(\d+([a-z]+|%|))\s+(\d+([a-z]+|%|)).*?;
```

I've replace your first `.*` with `[^;]*`, or anything *except* a semi-colon.  This will prevent the regex traversing past the first semicolon before matching the numeric values you are looking for.

I've also added a `.*?` before the final semi-colon, to allow it to traverse past any extra data after the two numeric values, such as "no-repeat" in your example.  That `.*?` could be replaced with `[^;]*`, if you prefer.

Comment: thanks this works great, and really identify the right backgoud properties, I am also trying to avoid background with right or left declaration `background...right 3px...` I had tries this regex `(background\s*:[^;]*?)!(right|left)(\d+([a-z]+|%|))\s+(\d+([a-z]+|%|))\s+.*?;` but it's seems to fail, how to I check that there is no right or left before the first (\d+([a-z]+|%|)) ???

Comment: You can [try a lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), like `(?!<(right|left))`